# If $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{50}(x-n)^{51n-n^2},$ then find $\frac{f(51)}{f'(51)}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

**My work so far follows:**

We have: $$\ln f(x)=\ln\left[\sum_{n=1}^{50} (x-n)^{51n-n^2}\right].$$ Now differentiating both sides w.r.t. $x,$ we obtain: $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{50}(51n-n^2)(x-n)^{51n-n^2-1}}{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{50}(x-n)^{51n-n^2}}.$$ Plugging in $x=51,$ we have: $$\frac{f'(51)}{f(51)}=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{50}(51n-n^2)(51-n)^{51n-n^2-1}}{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{50}(51-n)^{51n-n^2}}\\=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{50}n(51-n)^{51n-n^2}}{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{50}(51-n)^{51n-n^2}}.$$ How to handle this messy fraction? Please suggest..

Comment: Are you sure it's a sum? A product would be much easier.

Comment: Actually I found this question on a maths magazine (JEE related, India). So it could be that there is some typo (as I have witnessed some typing mistakes in other questions as well)! And yeah, a product would be much more easier after taking log. Being confused, posted it here...

Comment: The number you are looking for is not nice: it is a fraction whose numerator and denominator are 1 thousand digits number. The approximated value is $0.04529$. If it was a product like @AnginaSeng suggested, then the value would be much nicer, $\frac{1}{1275}$

Comment: @Raffaele, Yes sir. There might be product in place of sum..